# Issue with hiding/showing div tags in Explorer 10

Tags: html, internet-explorer-10

I have an .aspx web page with a series of div tags.
I'm going to post one of them as an example of what I'm doing:

```html
<div id="homeownerquestion" runat="server">
Are you the property owner?
<p>
    <asp:RadioButtonList ID="RadioButtonHomeowner" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" OnSelectedIndexChanged="rbHomeOwnerDecision">
        <asp:ListItem>Yes</asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem>No</asp:ListItem>
    </asp:RadioButtonList>
```

On the code behind page I have the following:

```cs
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    ClientScript.GetPostBackEventReference(this, string.Empty);
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        homeownerquestion.Visible = true;
        rejection.Visible = false;
        HazMap.Visible = false;
        WaitList.Visible = false;
        k2dlink.Visible = false;
        FloodPlain.Visible = false;
        floodinterest.Visible = false;
        PropertyAge.Visible = false;
        older1968.Visible = false;
        HomeType.Visible = false;
    }
    else
    {
        homeownerquestion.Visible = false;
        HazMap.Visible = false;
        FloodPlain.Visible = false;
        older1968.Visible = false;
        HomeType.Visible = false;

    }

}

protected void rbHomeOwnerDecision(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    if (RadioButtonHomeowner.SelectedItem.Text == "No")
    {
        rejection.Visible = true;
        k2dlink.Visible = true;
    }
    if (RadioButtonHomeowner.SelectedItem.Text == "Yes")
    {
        HazMap.Visible = true;
    }

}
```

These are all various divs that appear and disappear based on radio button selections.

This code works in every single browser I've tested EXCEPT Explorer 10. How do I force IE10 to backrun into IE 8 as there are some display issues with 9 even though it works,
Other suggestions welcome as well.

Comment: Do you get any errors in your browser console? This may be the result of a common ASP.NET Bug which fails to properly identify IE10. [There are solutions](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/BugAndFixASPNETFailsToDetectIE10CausingDoPostBackIsUndefinedJavaScriptErrorOrMaintainFF5ScrollbarPosition.aspx).

Comment: No not getting an error.

Comment: Try the fix suggested in [Scott's blog](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/BugAndFixASPNETFailsToDetectIE10CausingDoPostBackIsUndefinedJavaScriptErrorOrMaintainFF5ScrollbarPosition.aspx). I suspect this may be the issue.

Answer (score 0):

In most cases (I could say in all cases, but I haven't been in web development for that long), IE10 will work if IE9 works and so does either Chrome or Firefox. If it does not, for whatever reason, your users can use `Browser Mode` feature of IE 10:

[image]

This is done from Developer Tools, which you can access using F12.